# How can I query parse.com with VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parse-platform

I am having a hell of a time building a query in VB.Net.
"Item" is my parse class
"PLUNmbr" is a string column in that class

```
Private Async Sub btnSyncToCloud_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSyncToCloud.Click

Dim qItem As New ParseQuery(Of ParseObject)("Item")
qItem.WhereEqualTo("PLUNmbr", "0002")
Dim obj As Parse.ParseObject = Await qItem.FirstAsync

Debug.Print("PLUNmbr = " & obj("PLUNmbr").Value.ToString.Trim)
//This always prints out "0001" - which happens to be the first record in the class.
//No matter how I set the criteria - 0001 comes back.

end sub
```

Comment: Maybe it should be `qItem = qItem.WhereEqualTo("PLUNmbr", "0002")`

Comment: I owe you a beer! I'm proficient with Parse on ios/osx - but this is a new .NET project for me and I was completely lost. Bravo!

Comment: Cool, it was kinda a shot in the dark (I don't know VB) but I'll add it as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
qItem.WhereEqualTo("PLUNmbr", "0002")
```

doesn't *modify* `qItem`, it just returns a new instance with the filter added.  You'll want to change your code to:

```
qItem = qItem.WhereEqualTo("PLUNmbr", "0002")
```

I imagine you could also do:

```
Dim qItem As New ParseQuery(Of ParseObject)("Item")
Dim obj As Parse.ParseObject = Await qItem.WhereEqualTo("PLUNmbr", "0002").FirstAsync
```